# SQL Subquery using HAVING COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is: How do I show the name of each artist which has recorded at least one title at a studio where the band: "The Bullets" have recorded?

I have formulated the following query:

```
select ar.artistname, ti.titleid from artists ar
where exists
(
select 0
from titles ti where ti.artistid = ar.artistid
and exists
(
select 0
from studios s
where s.studioid = ti.studioid
and ar.artistname = 'The Bullets'
)
);
```

However, I need to include HAVING COUNT(ti.titleid) > 0 to satisfy this part, "each artist which has recorded at least one title" in the question.

I also am unsure as to how to match the artistname, "The Bullets" who have recorded at least one studio.

The Artists table resmebles the following:

```
Artists
-------
ArtistID, ArtistName, City
```

The Tracks table resmebles the following:

```
Tracks
------
TitleID, ArtistID, StudioID
```

The Studios table resmebles the folllowing:

```
Studios
-------
StudioID, StudioName, Address
```

I also **must specify that I cannot use joins**, e.g., a performance preference.

Comment: Your query is fine, you don't need the `HAVING COUNT(*)>0`. If one row exists, that's bigger than 0, isn't it?

Comment: Well, I'll need to know if the bullets have recorded at least one title at a studio where the band. Edited with that implementation. Is it correct? Would you say?

Comment: You cannot use joins? Why? Is this some kind of puzzle/homework?

Comment: You do know that joins typically perform **as well or better** than other methods.  SQL frameworks are designed to do joins quickly -- that is why they are called relational databases.

Comment: I would be hard pressed to know how multiple sub-queries perform faster than joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
select ArtistName from Artists where ArtistID in (
  select ArtistID from Tracks where StudioID in (
    select StudioID from Tracks where ArtistID in (
      select ArtistId from Artists where ArtistName='The Bullets'
    )
  )
)
```

I don't see why do you think `having` is needed.

Comment: I think he means he has to use having as a requirement

Comment: When formulated the question before posting i thought it to be necessary. Is it superfluous?

Comment: Yes. It is superfluous.

Comment: This answer will get totally correct results but will be a performance nightmare in almost all versions of MySQL.

Comment: Could you please explain? This kind of data doesn't seem to be really skewed neither too huge for me.

Comment: @LajosVeres It's a perfectly fine answer (I upvoted.) Just wanted to notice that `IN (SELECT ...)` subqueries do not perfrom very well in MySQL. When nested one inside the other, the result can be a really slow query, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

The studio(s) where the bullets recorded

```
SELECT StudioID
FROM Sudios S
JOIN Tracks T ON S.StudioID = S.StudioID
JOIN Artists A ON T.ArtistID = A.ArtistID AND A.ArtistName = 'The Bullets'
```

Every Artist who recorded there

```
SELECT A1.ArtistName, A1.City
FROM Artist A1
JOIN Tracks T1 ON T1.ArtistID = A2.ArtistID
WHERE T1.SudioID IN 
(
  SELECT StudioID
  FROM Sudios S
  JOIN Tracks T ON S.StudioID = S.StudioID
  JOIN Artists A ON T.ArtistID = A.ArtistID AND A.ArtistName = 'The Bullets'
) T
```

Answer (score 1):

These two requirements are quite silly - using HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 and no joins. I've never heard of choosing sub-queries over joins to enhance performance.

However, I think this query fulfills these requirements.

```
SELECT a.ArtistName FROM Artist a
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT t1.ArtistId FROM Track t1
    WHERE t1.ArtistId = a.ArtistId
    AND EXISTS
    (
         SELECT * FROM Track t2
         WHERE t1.StudioId = t2.StudioID
         AND t2.ArtistName = 'The Bullets'
    )
    GROUP BY t1.ArtistId, t1.StudioId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
);
```